# Get 415 error when using AddMvcCore for webapi

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, content-type

Everything works fine when using AddMvc for webapi call, but it throws 415 back when using AddMvcCore.

request header is set as

`Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
Accept: application/json`

Any thought ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out I just need to add one more line

`services.AddMvcCore()
        .AddJsonFormatters()`

I think it is because the Web API was like

`public string Post([FromBody] JObject arg)`

It requires json.net to convert the json string.

Related discussion is [here](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/2872)

Comment: You're the man! Starting with an empty web API project definitely has a few gotchas.